# You find me when your sad, And kill me when your mad

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I live on the shores and in the sea,
>
> The land won't be with me.
>
> I spend my time on the other side,
>
> Waiting for you to come beside,
>
> So you can die.
>
> You find me when your sad,
>
> And kill me when your mad.
>
> You chain me up, break me apart, and shave me down until I am nothing.
>
> When you come to me next, you meet the same fate,
>
> Murdered and killed like a little plate,
>
> All to clean your little slate.

**Who am I?**

Comment: is the lack of apostrophe in "wont" intentional?

Comment: @AustinWeaver No, it was not intentional

Comment: @AustinWeaver was that the only missing apostrophe here? Metapuzzle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are you a solute containing sodium chloride? (a salty fluid?)

I live on the shores and in the sea,

> Salt water

The land won't be with me.

> Fresh water is on land

I spend my time on the other side,

> on the other side of your skin is salty blood

Waiting for you to come beside,

> waiting for the blood to be beside your body instead of in it.

So you can die.

> without blood you die

You find me when your sad,

> Salty tears

And kill me when your mad.

> a reference to damaging one's circulatory system.

You chain me up, break me apart, and shave me down until I am nothing.

> a reference to the heart as a chamber for salty blood "chain my heart", "break my heart", "becoming heartless" all song lyrics about the body's salt-fluid pump

When you come to me next, you meet the same fate,

> now this person is slitting their own wrist; he is coming in contact with his own blood on purpose!

Murdered and killed like a little plate,

> a little plate can be broken as easily as you can kill yourself

All to clean your little slate.

> suicide might be to clean one's slate of guilt or shame

Comment: Impressive! Correct! Congratulations!